# Implementing locks and semaphores for multi-processor systems?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, multiprocessing

In reviewing some system software concepts, I'm looking through my old OS project done on a simulated uniprocessor. I'm wondering how the concepts of locks and semaphores would extend to say a quad-core computing device.

Would you need atomic hardware instruction support, e.g. a test-and-set that synchronizes the cores in hardware? I'm just not sure how this would work out, and what the options are for multiprocessors, that's my question.

Comment: "For reference I've provided some old code I used, though it's not necessary for the discussion. " - thanks for that...Not a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something from the hardware. An atomic test-and-set operation is an example of something that you could use. Exactly what you need is actually platform-specific because the problems you need to solve are platform-specific. For example, if your platform has write re-ordering, you need some way to prevent your writes from being re-ordered. If it doesn't, you don't.

There's really no good way to answer this generically.